# EF Core Code First - One to Many relationship without Id

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, relationship

Given are two models looking like this

```
public class ParentEntity {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class ChildEntity {
    [Key]
    public string ISOCode {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The relationsship should be ParentEntity * ----- 1 ChildEntity. I'm not sure how I would "configure" this relationship in the ParentEntity model as in this case ChildEntity Key is not an integer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Parent" name is a bit misleading since it appears at the dependent side of the relationship (1 = principal, * = dependent). So it requires FK. It doesn't need to be `int`, should be the same type as the principal PK (in this case, `string`).

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. So if I write `public ChildEntity ChildEntity { get; set; }` and `public string ChildEntityISOCode {get; set; }` on ParentEntity EF will understand what will be the FK?

Comment: I guess so - that's by EF Core naming conventions. But you can call them as you with and use data annotations/fluent API to tell EF the mapping. Following naming conventions is better/preferable though. Just in case you want cascade delete and required relationship (i.e. parent requires child (he-he, that's why parent is not a good name, but I know it is not real)), then at least mark `ChildEntity` or `ChildEntityISOCode` with `[Required]` attribute

Comment: Great, thank you again for your help.